# homogenous equation substitution mistake

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

My teacher gave me this equation to solve which is a homogeneous equation. In this type of equation, we usually use t substitutions. But in this one I cannot find what should I substitute t with? Any help?

$$ 2xdy+(x^2y^4+1)ydx=0$$

Any help would be appreciated)

Comment: yeah, i tired that too, didn't worked @Moo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This equation is not homogeneous. Hint: Write it as
$$ y'+\frac{1}{2x}y=-\frac12xy^5 \tag1$$
which is a Bernoulli equation. Then let $u=y^{1-5}=y^{-4}$ to change (1) into a linear equation.

Comment: Omg! Thank You! You have no idea how much this helped me

Comment: Glad I can help you.

Answer (score 1):

$$2xdy+(x^2y^4+1)ydx=0$$
Multiply by $y$:
$$2yxdy+(x^2y^4+1)y^2dx=0$$
$$(xdy^2+y^2dx)+x^2y^6dx=0$$
$$d(xy^2)+x^2y^6dx=0$$
$$\dfrac {d(xy^2)}{(xy^2)^3}+\dfrac {dx}x=0$$
Integrate:
$$\dfrac {1}{(xy^2)^2}-2\ln |x|=C$$

Comment: thanks a lot)))

Comment: you are welcome @jane